# My Producer Consumer code is going in Deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

The code is going into deadlock. Even if it is going to Producer part as soon as it hits `wait()`, it goes into deadlock. From my understanding, if `wait()` is hit, it should go to consumer thread instead of going into deadlock.

```
package com.java.thread.self.practice;

public class Producer_Consumer {

        private volatile boolean prodFlag = true;
        private volatile boolean consFlag = false;

        public static void main(String[] args){

            Producer_Consumer producer_Consumer = new Producer_Consumer();
            producer_Consumer.startThreads();

        }

        private void startThreads() {

            Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true){
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Before Producer invocation :::::: ");
                            producer();
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }

            });



            Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(true){
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Before Consumer invocation :::::: ");
                            consumer();
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            });


            producer.start();
            consumer.start();
        }

         void producer() throws InterruptedException {

             System.out.println("Inside the producer method ::::: "+this.getClass());

             synchronized(this){

                 if(prodFlag){

                     System.out.println("PRODUCE !!!");
                     consFlag = true;
                     System.out.println("Before calling wait in producer :::::: ");
                     notify();
                     wait();
                     System.out.println("After calling wait in producer :::::: ");

                 }else{

                     System.out.println("Before calling notify in producer :::::: ");
                     consFlag = true;
                     wait();
                     System.out.println("After calling notify in producer :::::: ");

                 }


             }
        }

         void consumer() throws InterruptedException {

             System.out.println("Inside the consumer method ::::: "+this.getClass());

             synchronized(this){

                 if(consFlag){

                     System.out.println("CONSUME !!!");
                     prodFlag = true;
                     System.out.println("Before calling wait in consumer :::::: ");
                     notify();
                     wait();
                     System.out.println("After calling wait in consumer :::::: ");

                 }else{

                     System.out.println("Before calling notify in consumer :::::: ");
                     prodFlag = true;

                     wait();

                     System.out.println("After calling wait in consumer :::::: ");

                 }

             }
        }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it doesn't deadlock. He continuosly print "Produce" "Consume" in console

Comment: Try in Debug mode.

Comment: What happens if both your producer thread and your consumer thread call `notify()` and then they both call `wait()`?  What were you thinking would wake either one of them up again?

Comment: @james large Can you suggest me a good link, if I am missing some concept.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Thanks. I will read and try to update the code

Answer (score 2):

When you do this

```
synchronized(this)
```

you lock the whole class. And it will be locked until the end of that code block. Since you declare your flags `volatile` there shouldn't be a need for explicit synchronization.

In this case you don't need to signal `wait()` and `notify` at all. However, if you want to have some atomic business logic you will need to rework your code to not block the whole big block with your class as a key.

Comment: "here shouldn't be a need for explicit synchronization." Aside from the fact [you have to hold the monitor to call wait and notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).

Comment: Thanks for your input.
Even though I tried removing with volatile key word, it still goes into deadlock. My question is if it hits wait(), it should go to Consumer thread instead of going to deadlock.

Comment: My question is why it is not going to consumer block, once it hits the wait() in producer block.

Comment: Try in Debug mode.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks, that's correct. I only noticed that he does not consume any other variable from both branches nor is there a need for atomicity. I edited my reply

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not go into deadlock - neither when running, nor when debugging. I suppose you're not familiar with debugging more than one thread, right? Maybe it seems to you, that your producing thread is in a deadlock while you have to switch to the consuming thread and continue debugging?